# Location for saving a temporary file

Tags: add-on-development, filesystem

Is there a designated location for saving temporary files for serving to the user?

I dynamically create a PDF file and need to save it somewhere for the user to download. Which directory should I use to store these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific location set by ExpressionEngine. Addons use the cache folder for dynamically generated files, but if you're creating an actual PDF I would create a tmp directory in the public_html directory.

Comment: The files location is up to developer, but if the PDFs are user-specific, I would save them in user personal folders (location again is up to you). If the content is sensitive, I would place the files outside of public_html and retrieve using add-on like [Protected Links](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/protected-links)

Comment: That Protected Links addon is a very good suggestion. Kudos.